# Calculated field based on a field in another list

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column, site-column, spfield

I would like to create a calculated field which requires a digit. This digit must be between a Max and Min value which are two ListItems in another list.
How can I create a formula for this calucated field to check that the value is not less than Min and not more than Max?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this by adding script to the NewForm and EditForm that reads the values from the other list. You can hook into PreSaveAction as well so that the user doesn't have to wait for the server to reject the save; you can handle it client side.

Answer (score 2):

You can not because a Calculated Formula only operates on ONE Item in ONE List

So your workarounds

- make a workflow copy Min/Max values from List B to every ListItem in List A
- Use No Calculations; Let the View (using CSR or other scripting) display the incorrect value
- On every change Min/Max in List B, update the Formula in List A definition with those (hardcoded) values
- ??

Comment: Thanks Danny, unfortunately I can't copy items from listB to listA. What about adding a Script Web Part to the NewForm and make validation using JavaScript? Have I any other good alternative?

Comment: Sure, that is the option 2, and is a modern approach, Be sure to use CSR Client-Side-Rendering; and use the Chrome Cisar plugin to develop it the easy way